# What does this function produce

Tags: haskell

What is the type and the value of the expression:

```
do [1,2,3]; "lambda"
```

I tested it and found out  that it just print lambda 3 times. 
But i don't understand why it does that.
how can i rewrite it using bind. It feels like it is necessary to rewrite it.

Comment: no it was an old exam question. 
so i think it is okay to ask for help here.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your code is the same as

```
[1, 2, 3] >> "lambda"
```

`>>` is defined as

```
m >> n = m >>= \_ -> n
```

And `>>=` operator is defined for lists as:

```
xs >>= f = concat (map f xs)
```

So, your code may be translated into:

```
concat $ map (const "lambda") [1, 2, 3]
```

Which produces the result

```
"lambdalambdalambda"
```

Answer (score 0):

here is the same output with bind:

```
λ> [1,2,3] >>= \x -> "lambda"
"lambdalambdalambda"
```

What did you expect to get?

Comment: I didn't thought it would work because we have no return.
what is λ>
[1,2,3] >>= \x -> "lambda"
we bind a list to a function that produces "lambda" as result.
how come is it applied three times.

Comment: what is λ>? 
And why is function applied three times?

Comment: It's nothing important.  I saw it in a youtube tutorial and liked it.  Inside ghci you can change the prompt setting by running ':set prompt <whateveryouwant>'.  To have ghci set it every time you start a new session you can add it to your .ghci file in you home directory

Comment: should i think like this?
i have a box with 1,2,3 and for each of them o apply the lambda function and concat the result.

Comment: soon's answer is much better than mine so you should probably up vote his answer and ignore mine.  If you found any of my comment responses useful you could up vote that.

Answer (score 0):

by definition of list monad,

```
do [1,2,3]; "lambda"      -- "lambda" = ['l','a','m','b','d','a']
  = [1,2,3] >>= (\x -> "lambda")
  = [r | x <- [1,2,3], r <- "lambda"]
```

for list monad `return x = [x]`, and so the usual use-case of

```
do x <- [1,2,3]; return x
  = [r | x <- [1,2,3], r <- [x]]
```

gets shortcut into just `[x | x <- [1,2,3]]`. This uses the monad law ***`m >>= return = m`***.

But the last monadic value in a `do` sequence, of type `m a` (here, `[a]`), doesn't have to be a singleton list. It can be empty, or hold several elements.

As for the type of the result, it is `[Char]`. First of all, `do` represents a *bind* chain, and the type of *bind* is

```
(>>=) :: m a -> ( a -> m b) -> m b
```

Since in your example the monadic values are lists, we conclude that `m = []`. The last value is of type `String` which is `[Char]`, and so according to the above signature, this is the type of the result.